# Cucumber not working with rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, connection, cucumber

our rails application (along with cucumber tests associated with it) make a call/request to an external rest API. The rails server dev environment works fine with this when it is supposed to, but recently the cucumber tests have stopped interacting with the rest API, even when it should be on and is interacting with the dev server fine. (I get Errno - Connection refused)

Previously, we had the proper port to access it hard coded for simplicity. Somebody (who wasn't me) made a change to remove the hard code as well along with other changes, but they didn't completely work and so a few others and I changed back to hardcode in order to get the development environment working. Now, the development environment works exactly like it should, but the cucumber tests send a connection refused error as if the rest API server is not on, even when it is. I wish I could give more info on this, but as I didn't make the change, I don't know what all has changed.

I am wondering if anybody has any experience with something like this, and if they know what the problem could be and why the rails server development environment server works but the cucumber testing does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've hardcoded the port number for development environment alone , the test environment will not be able to see this. Use a configuration file like this :

`config/config.yml` :

```
default: &defaults
  api_port: 80

development:
  <<: *defaults
  api_port: 3000

production:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults
  api_port: 8080
```

`config/initializers/config.rb` :

```
AppConfig = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
```

Use the config `AppConfig[:api_port]` in your code and it will respect the environment now.